# My app crashes after i try upload image from gallery

Tags: android-studio, uri, navigation-drawer, picasso, android-image

I try upload image from gallery with this code:

```
    public void oc_chooseImage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (  );
    intent.setType ( "image/*" );
    intent.setAction ( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT );
    startActivityForResult (intent,1);
}

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult ( requestCode, resultCode, data );

    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData () != null)
    {
        imageUri = data.getData ();
        mv_logo.setImageURI ( imageUri );
        nav_logo.setImageURI ( imageUri );
    }
}
```

What can be the problem? my minimum version in android studio is 19 api, i try run my app with my phone and the gallery just crashes and stops my app.

Comment: please add the logcat error which app crashes

Comment: I dont get an error.

Answer (score 0):

My app run very slowly or crashes when i try to upload big images.